Bolding text is not working in different devices
Is bolding text is affected by screen type?
This is JSX in react:


function App() {
  return (
    // Problem Here
    <b className="info-text">Info:{" "}</b>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
.info-text {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #15366D;
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>




Depends on whether the font family supports it.

bolder is relative - so what is the full context here - what is the font weight of the parent?

From mdn docs: "Meaning of relative weights"

Note that when using relative weights, only four font weights are
considered — thin (100), normal (400), bold (700), and heavy (900). If
a font family has more weights available, they are ignored for the
purposes of relative weight calculation.

In other words:
if your body was set to font-weight: 400
an element with font-weight:lighter would render the weight 100 – not as maybe expected 300.
This also applies to fonts supporting a wide range of weights (e.g variable fonts)


@font-face {
  font-family: 'Noto Serif';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100 900;
  font-stretch: 62.5% 100%;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/notoserif/v23/ga6Iaw1J5X9T9RW6j9bNfFcWaA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

body{
  font-family:'Noto Serif';
  font-weight:400
}


.lighter{
  font-weight:lighter
}

.light{
  font-weight:light
}

.bolder{
 font-weight:bolder
}

.bold{
 font-weight:bold
}

.info-text {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #15366D;
}
<h3>Implicit/relative weights</h3>
<p class="info-text lighter">p-lighter </p>
<b class="info-text bolder">b-bolder</b>

<h3>Explicit weights</h3>
<p class="info-text light">p-light </p>
<b class="info-text bold">b-bold</b>



If you need a consistent cross-browser rendering:

load webfonts - don't rely on system default fonts for serif or sans-serif
use explicit font-weights (bold/700 etc)


I think you should use the <span> tag rather than the <b> tag.
See this example:


.info-text {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #f00;
}
<span class="info-text">
  Info
</span>



Note: Do convert this into JSX and use className instead of class.

The b tag may well be wanted here. It doesn't nowadays mean 'embolden' - it means 'bring attention to'. Also why has font-weight been changed to bold when the OP wanted bolder - which is different.

You can use specific numeric values for font-weight (e.g., 600 for semi-bold, 700 for bold).

The OP wanted bolder which is a relative value, meaning one up from the parent font weight. Your answer assumes the parent weight is known which may not be the case.
